# Reading double Value PIC18F67K22

Tags: c, embedded, pic

```
char q[150];
void main(void){

System_Initialization();
UART_Init_2();

 while(1){ 

 double A=23.045610;
 sprintf(q,"%f\r\n",A);    
 UART_Tx_2(q);}}
```

When I Read value of A its give 23.045410 instead of 23.045610
anyone know why this will happened?
i am using PIC18F67k22 controller and Xc8 Compiler

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Why are you using floating point on a lousy PIC with no FPU?

Comment: @Lundin, I think you were too hasty closing this question. The surprising behaviour here is that you get so few digits of precision with doubles.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Feel free to find a better duplicate. These kind of questions have been asked thousands of times before.

Comment: @lundin The dupes are indeed wrong, as it's related to a compiler setting of the pic chip (which defaults to 32bit doubles)

Comment: Did find the right dupe btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412584/rounding-issue-when-using-long-long-on-pic

Comment: ok thanks for replying

Answer (score 2):

On the PIC18, the data types float and double are the same, and only 32 bits long. That is not enough bits to store more than five or so decimal digits. Therefore you can expect some rounding error at the end of the decimals.